# CSS: how do i make "border-top" of a link into an image when my mouse hovers over the link

Tags: css

i was wondering if there is a way to change the border-top and border-bottom into a specific border i made myself. It's an image and i wanted it to be shown when the use hovers over the link.

Is that possible? or would i have to make my links into images and then have the image change into another image of the link with borders. (This seems like the long way around it. I was hoping there is a easier method)

This is my code. Everything works fine. I just want to replace the solid borders with an image border i made myself.

CSS:

```
.home   {
font: bold 15px;
    text-align:center;
height:30px;
width: 223px;
    background-color: #d0d1cf;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
position:absolute;
left:80px;
top:200px;
}

.home:hover {
        background-color:#b2b4b0;
        border-top:solid 1px #ffffff;
        border-bottom:solid 1px #ffffff;
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="home">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There is `border-image`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a background-image on hover which will have both the borders you want to show.

```
a {
border-top:5px;
border-bottom:5px;
height:50px;
}
a:hover {
border:none;
background-image:url(image.jpg);
height:60px;/*normal height + missing borders*/
}
```

All you need to do is create an image with the top border on top, the bottom border on bottom which has the height of the element + the height of both borders added.

Also, once you remove the borders on hover, you need to adjust the height of the element, so it doesnt change its height because of the missing borders.

True height = height prop + borders + padding.

I wouldnt use border image for this as it is not yet widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
div
{
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Old Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

Please read more about border-image at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Note that border-image is not supported by IE

Comment: i saw this earlier on another post. But i wanted something all browsers would be able to use. Thank you again for answering though.